# Unable to load annotation processor factory in vs code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, immutables-library

I am trying to use the `immutables` library with vscode (and Gradle).

Steps I've taken:

1. Confirmed that the `jar` exists
2. Ensured that the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` variable exists (it didn't initially)
3. Set the "java.import.gradle.home" vscode setting (GRADLE_HOME)
4. Ensured project builds using `gradle build`

I keep getting hung up on the environment variable. `GRADLE_USER_HOME` vs `GRADLE_HOME`.

I'm on MacOS and I did not install vscode using `brew`, but actually downloaded the app from the vscode website.

`Unable to load annotation processor factory 'GRADLE_USER_HOME/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.immutables/value/2.7.3/91d271437be1e14438a2da6c5c3e9f8db061a7b9/value-2.7.3.jar' for project`

Answer (score 0):

GRADLE_USER_HOME doesn't point to an $Environment variable that can be evaluated -- it looks like you have an issue in how you are retrieving and hydrating the value that GRADLE_USER_HOME points to --

You said that you "***Set the "java.import.gradle.home" vscode setting (GRADLE_HOME)***"

Your error message reads:

```
Unable to load annotation processor factory 'GRADLE_USER_HOME/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.immutables/value/2.7.3/91d271437be1e14438a2da6c5c3e9f8db061a7b9/value-2.7.3.jar' for project
```

Looking at your error string: -- it seems that you probably did this:

```
java.import.gradle.home: GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

In order to collect an $Environment variable into your Java code, the setting in your properties file (or Yaml) should look like this:

```
java.import.gradle.home: ${{GRADLE_USER_HOME}}
```

Comment: This was a good guess, but no. I set it as such:

    "java.import.gradle.home": "/Users/william/.gradle",

I appreciate your help!